# Chrome app upload fail

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I modified some image files and ' **manifast** ' files, then removed the " **app** " value and uploaded it incorrectly 
So I put in the " **app** " value back and tried to upload it again. But I am getting the below error.

ErrrorMessage :

> An error occurred: Failed to process your item. This item is not an
>   app, please remove app section from manifest.

Please tell me how to go back to the previous version or fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by contacting Google Support. Maybe it was an internal error in the chrome app store developer server.